What is the maximum load for lateral loading of a screw?
I want to build the following swing for my grandkids:

So I reckon that there will be a lateral loading on the countersunk bolt (shown in red), I would like to know what is the maximum load (in kg) that a given bolt (let's say an M6 bolt) can withstand
Thanks in advance!
PS: I know that there are easier ways to build a swing with swinging part hanging from a hook, but my daughter wishes to have it this way...

Looks like a device designed to remove fingers. Shear strength is available in many places.

Does this answer your question? Metric bolt shear strength for a layman

"designed to remove fingers"? What part doesn't seems safe?

So you only have an M6 nut between the wood of the swing and the wood of the support - nice shearing action for fingers or did you miss that?

Well the drawing is not to scale, so the space between the nut and the wooden parts wouldn't be so big as to fit a finger inside. The nut is just a spacer between the two wooden parts, so at most a fraction of a mm should be between nut and wooden part

You have not measured the nut then, or are you countersinking it? So you seem to be creating a pair of scissors...

Recommend you put a heavy rope in a sturdy tree, design a seat, test it when created and multiple times throughout it's life with excess weight (like yourself), and they're likely to forget the alternate design.
